# How to keep child elements from inheriting any parent styles?

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I am including my content inside a parent page. I need to make sure I am not inheriting any of the styles set in the parent.

I want to make sure that the parent still has those styles applied to the content but for my content which is loaded via Ajax call my styles are applied.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but `$("*").each(function{ ... })` may help.

Comment: +1, use an iframe. If that's not an option, you could do something similar to [YUI Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Comment: Your question's title seems to be asking something very different to your question's body.

Comment: I guess the title prescribes a possible solution which I had in mind, but the ultimate goal is the question body. I should probably rename the title.

Comment: I revised the title of this question to match what is described in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to override every single style setting from parents.  You'd have to do something like a style reset, but if you were doing it via CSS, you'd even have to make sure you have enough specificity to make sure you're overrides apply.

Your best bet might be to use an iframe which gets a totally clean style context.

If you know which style values are an issue, you could manually set every one of those on your own content container, but if you don't know, you'd have to cover every single style attribute there is (which would be very inefficient and not very practical).

Comment: I am tempted to go with this approach but hoping there is another way. I am surprised there is no library for this.

Comment: @AndrewDouglas - quite honestly it's one of the things that iframes are there for - when completely foreign content from a different source is being put inside of some other content and you want the foreign content to stand on it's own.  So, in a way, the solution does exist.

Comment: I am going to go with iframes this time. Thank you all for your advice and help. It seems that the idea of manipulating style attributes for parent content is just too complex.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following code which would reset the styles to blank... you could probably add your own too...

```
$('body').find("*").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('style').length > 1){
        $this.attr('style','');
    }
})
```

Comment: This isn't what they want to do.  They want to just keep their own content inserted in the page from inheriting styles rules from parent objects.  They want other objects in the page to be unchanged.

Comment: @jfriend00 - This answer does exactly what the question _title_ says to do, but it's kind of opposite to what the question _body_ says to do.

Comment: @nnnnnn - yeah they are in conflict.  The OP's comments say it's the body description that they desire.  I will propose an edit of the title to clarify.

Comment: I guess now that the question has been updated... it would be nice for you to go for the iframe option rather than having to change the main css

Comment: +1 for the effort you put in even though it is no longer applicable. It was exactly what the original title asked for...